# Is BootCampDrivers.com safe?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, security, graphics, driver

I've had tons of scaling and performance issues in scaling of 3D applications and games under Windows on my MacBook Pro 16" 2019 (MBP 16,1) due to the extremely outdated AMD drivers Apple ships with BootCamp. Searching online, the solution appears to be installing a customized version of more modern drivers from BootCampDrivers.com, a website providing improved 3D drivers for Macs running Windows. Before putting anything valuable on my Mac, I decided to give them a try and - as expected - everything was smooth and scaling issues (making any fullscreen game unplayable) were fixed. I have since wiped Windows and was planning to reinstall it fresh now.

While the drivers work amazing, I cannot find much info on the Internet about how they are getting made. How can I ensure that they do not contain malware of some sort? I doubt someone is deploying a trojan specifically made for users of high-end MacBooks running Windows who are looking for drivers that aren't several years old, but is there a way to be a bit more sure, perhaps by actually comparing the drivers with the original ones?

It appears that the custom installer of AMD graphics drivers also installs a certificate root to enable signed BootCampDrivers.com code. Does this provide any sort of security or can anyone create such a certificate to be approved by Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Apple does recommend visiting AMD's website for updated Windows graphics drivers. See [Boot Camp Support](https://support.apple.com/boot-camp) or more specifically [Update AMD graphics drivers for Windows in Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208908). I would assume AMD would provide the most up-to-date drivers for their products. Also, often Apple Software Update and as well as Microsoft Update will provide updated drivers for Windows hardware.

Comment: None of those work, I've already tried all of them. Standard drivers need to be modified in order to work on my Mac.

Comment: If there are better drivers out there that Apple did not include in Boot Camp, then this may be because these drivers can cause overheating which could result in damage.