# dx11 feature level 10.0 is required to run the engine issue on bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp

I have macOS(macbook pro 2018) Catalina and I have windows 10 on Bootcamp. I have directx 12 installed with 10_0 present ald all the accelerations enabled. Why do I get this?[image]
I also get this error when I start the windows saying there is an issue with my amd driver[image]

This error with the amd driver appeared only after I tried uptading all my dirvers with driver easy.

I have the game installed on a different ssd if that matters.

[Is BootCampDrivers.com safe?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387581/is-bootcampdrivers-com-safe)
that solved the issue. thanks a lot

Comment: What is the model/year of your Mac?

Comment: macbook pro 2018

Comment: Did  you use the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows 10? If not, then how did you install? I assume you installed the Windows Support Software after installing Windows. Also did you try Apple Software Update and/or Windows Update? Does this question/answer help solve your problem: [Is BootCampDrivers.com safe?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387581/is-bootcampdrivers-com-safe)

Comment: yes, I used Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows 10. I ll look to the other thread and try what he did